# Aws EKS: How to scalling pods based on SQS Metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics, amazon-eks

I'm migrating some of my applications that today is running on EC2 with Auto Scalling to k8.

Today my Auto Scalling is based on `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` metric from SQS queues (That i configured on CloudWatch).

I trying to figure out if i can use this metric to scalling pods of my application in AWS EKS environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install [k8s-cloudwatch-adapter](https://github.com/awslabs/k8s-cloudwatch-adapter)
2. [Deploy HPA](https://github.com/awslabs/k8s-cloudwatch-adapter/blob/master/samples/sqs/README.md) with custom metrics from AWS SQS.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out

Comment: The k8s-cloudwatch-adapter project has been archived, and recomends using [KEDA](https://keda.sh/) mentioned in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705451/875806)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using this for future, I would suggest using [keda](https://keda.sh/)..They support different type of scalers, you can scale your pods based on events.